# Toast message on Custom Listview Click in Android

Tags: android, listview, toast

I have a custom listview in which one textview and one checked box is in each row. 
When I click the ckeckbox, I want to add the value from TextView to database and to display a Toast message in the view. The database insertion is working fine. But the application is stopping suddently, and the Toast message is not shown in the view.

```
 public class Favourites extends Activity 
 {
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_list);
        ListView listitems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView_01);
        listitems.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(this));
     }
     private static class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter
     {
        //imp
        public View getView(int position,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {

              if (convertView == null)
              {
                  int itemId=SubListIdList.get(position);
                  TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView_02);
                  CheckBox star = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.star);
                  star.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 

                  {

                       @Override
                       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked)
                       {
                           Favourites f=new Favourites();
                           query="UPDATE "+SUB_TABLE_NAME+" SET FavoriteIndicator='Y' WHERE SubListID="+itemId;
                           db.execSQL(query);   
                           Toast.makeText(f, "Insertion successfull!", 1).show();
                       }
                 }
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Please help me.... Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the `Toast` notification your main activitiy's context to display it. I'm not quite sure why you are instantiating your activity again in the `onCheckedChanged()` method but I guess you were trying to pass your `Toast` a context with that. Try it this way.

```
Context ctx = null;

onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    // more stuff
    ctx = getApplication();

    // even more stuff
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
        query="UPDATE "+SUB_TABLE_NAME+" SET FavoriteIndicator='Y' WHERE" +
        " SubListID="+itemId;
        db.execSQL(query);   
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Insertion successfull!", 4000).show();
    }
}
```

And please don't set your `Toast` display time to one millisecond that won't help you. The time parameters is set in milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you so much.. it is working fine... but  the Toast display time duration '1' is working fine for me..

Answer (score 1):

You can directly toast like this,

```
Toast.makeText(Favourites.this, "Toast!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've a question about your code....what if `convertview != null`
is there any assumption why you skip that check?